# Cabal install needs C library: Windows

Tags: haskell, sqlite, yesod, cabal-install

I am trying to `cabal install yesod` on my Windows machine. I have a relatively fresh install of the Haskell Platform. The cabal install failed, reporting that I need the sqlite3 C library in order to install "persistent", a package which Yesod relies upon.

> ```
> cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
> * Missing C library: sqlite3
> ```

So I went to http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and grabbed both the C source and the precompiled binary. I tried using both, to no avail:

```
cabal install persistent --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Path\To\C\Source\Files
cabal install persistent --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Path\To\Binary
```

In both cases, I got the same result: it didn't work. :( What can I do to give cabal the C library it needs? (sqlite3 in this case)

Comment: Which version of GHC and cabal are you using?

Comment: GHC 7.0.3, cabal-install version 0.10.2, Windows 7 (32 bit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, facepalm. I didn't need the source, I didn't need the exe. **I needed the dll.**

Under the "precompiled binaries for Windows" section of the website mentioned in my question, I downloaded and extracted the zip file with `sqlite3.def` and `sqlite.dll`. Then I used

```
cabal install persistent --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Path\To\DllAndDef
```

The installation appears to have completed successfully. Afterwards, I did a `cabal install yesod`, which also appears to have completed successfully.

I suppose if I had put the dll somewhere magical, then I wouldn't have had to use the `--extra-lib-dirs=` option.