# Cabal: lifted-base-0.1.1 won't install because of "unrecognized option"

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal

I'm trying to install `hdbc-sqlite` with Cabal in Windows. I found some help from [this nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382334/cabal-install-needs-c-library-windows), but the installation of Sqlite3's dll and def files failed on a package called `lifted-base-0.1.1` because of an unrecognized option `--disable-benchmarks`.

Maybe I could fix this problem by modifying the installer's source code and removing this unrecognized option, and then manually installing the package, if manual installations are possible? Or is there a less tedious solution?

Comment: Which versions of Cabal and cabal-install are you using?

Comment: Version 1.14.0. I'm using an .exe file that I downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `cabal update`?

I would first try a more recent version (of [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2)) like `0.1.2` or `0.2`. Then I would manually download the [tar](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lifted-base/0.2/lifted-base-0.2.tar.gz) file and use this (change the path in the `import` command).

Also try to upgrade your GHC / Haskell platform, you apparently describe a [known issue](https://github.com/basvandijk/lifted-base/issues/8).

Comment: I'm surprised by how I could miss such a common sense solution. I'm updating Cabal now. I'll report back on what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm downloading the latest Haskell Platform now.